# Manual ray cast when a plane is not in the hit results during a ARCore session

Tags: arcore

I am creating points on a detected plane, but sometimes the plane is not tracked anymore (fast movement for example) and a hitTest may not return a hit on this plane.

ARKit will return hit result for every known plane could ARCore do the same?

Apparently, this notion exists in Unreal integration (EGoogleARCoreLineTraceChannel::InfinitePlane), could it be available in the Java API?

Also to work around this problem, I do a manual ray cast and for some reason, I have a really small offset between my computed position and the hitTest result. [image: the two dots show the offset blue is my cast and green is hit test result]

A Screen to World coordinates would help to make sure no bias is introduced there. Is that something possible?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Julien.

Answer (score 0):

As a current alternative I used the code from Jonas Jongejan and Dan Moore [AR Drawing](https://github.com/googlecreativelab/ar-drawing-java) to get the right Ray origin and it is working much better.

The secret was to generate 2 points near and front screen point and start the ray at `touchRay.direction.scale(AppSettings.getStrokeDrawDistance());`. I now have a very accurate match between my manual ray cast and the result of the `hitTest`.